# MySQL: Select with left join -> Rename results

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I've got a little question.

I would like to select data that are attached to the id of an entry.

For example:

table1:

```
id | userid 
1 , 2
2, 3
```

table2:

```
id | connectedid | type | value
1 , 1 , test, 5
2, 1, foo, 100
3, 2, cid, 7
```

Okay - now I would like to get all entries for table1.id = 1 - this would be:

```
id = 1
userid = 2
connectedid = 1
type = test
value = 5
```

and

```
id = 1
userid = 2
connectedid = 1
type = foo
value = 100
```

Now comes the tricky part. The field "type" changes often. Now I would like to get an result that names the row "value" after the content of "type".

Example-Result:

```
id = 1
userid = 2
connectedid = 1
foo = 100
```

How could I do that?

Thanks a lot in advance :-)

Comment: You want to change the column name at the runtime? I dont get you

Comment: why would you want to do the last part?

Comment: Hi - thank you for your answer. I would really like to get this result back to my php-app which is going to use this result for other processes. But: It uses a lot of different data and I would really love to get one object and get all attached data with the given type as object-member.

So if there is an result with type "mail", I could easily choose $result->mail. But only if there is an result like that.